# How to add insert the custom actions inside the existing Active Workspace Page?

Tags: siemens, siemens-nx

I am new to Siemens' Teamcenter Active workspace, An Angularjs based framework for Product LifeCycle Management [PLM]. I need to do some customization in the existing UI.

Background:

I have Teamcenter / Active Workspace installed on IIS and access it using the URL like [http://hostname:8080/awc12/#/](http://HTTP://hostname:8080/awc12/#/) [Default URL of the basic Installation of Teamcenter Active worksapce]

I have created another Active workspace module using generateModule script provided by "Active workspace environment" and deployed on the IIS server and access it as an http://hostname:8080/myModule/#/mySubLocation

I want to insert a button on the Panel of the basic installation [http://hostname:8080/awc12/#/com.siemens.splm.clientfx.tcui.xrt.showObject?uid=xxx](http://hostname:8080/awc12/#/)

Upon clicking this button I want to launch newly created module http://hostname:8080/myModule/#/mySubLocation as a Modal dialog

Questions:

1. What steps do I need to take so that I can achieve adding the new button and opening a modal with my module page?
2. Where can I find the list of APIs that are exposed by Teamcenter Active workspace
3. Is there any document/site where I can find some Hello World applications with code?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Siemens provides this PDF on "Configuration and Extensibility" for Active Workspace 4.3:
https://docs.plm.automation.siemens.com/data_services/resources/aw/4.3/aw_pdf_collection/tdoc/en_US/pdf/configuration_and_extensibility.pdf

And this location also might contain useful information:
https://docs.plm.automation.siemens.com/docs/aw/4.3/en_US/ui_pattern_library/#/showcase/

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](/help/deleted-answers)